# React-Materialize change brand text color

Tags: reactjs

I think I have found an error with React-Materialize. Still new, probably won't stop people from being harsh ;).

Using the normal means of changing the text color i.e.

```
`className="black-text"`
```

does not work. I was forced to change it manually by finding the element

```
`nav .brand-logo {
  color: black;
}`
```

and making the change within my own css file. I wanted to stay within the framework, but could not get anything to work. Here is my complete React-Materialize element:

```
`<Navbar brand="ARWA" className="transparent black-text" right>
    <NavItem href="get-started.html">
      <div className="blue-text">Getting started </div>
    </NavItem>
    <NavItem href="components.html">
      <div className="blue-text"> Components</div>
    </NavItem>
 </Navbar>`
```

I took a look at the source code, but to no avail. No gleaming errors stood out to me. This may be an opportunity for someone better than I to make a contribution. Or at least see what I'm doing wrong and help me change the `brand` color within the React-Materialize framework.

Answer (score 1):

## Changing Text Color of React Attribute

If you want to edit the color of text within an attribute tag or add an image into the tag, you can put your code into a JSX variable and pass that variable into the attribute tag in react-materialize.

### Changing Text Color

```
import YourStuff
import reactThings

const brandColor = <span style={{color: "#FFFFFF"}}>Your Brand</span>;

class Header extends Component {
    ...
    <Navbar className="Header red" brand={brandColor} right />
}
```

**brandColor** changes whatever the default color was to **#FFFFFF** which is white. Make sure brandColor is outside of the component class.

### Inserting Image

```
import Logo as "./logo.png";

const Img = <img src={Logo} alt={"YourBrand"}/>;

class Header extends Component {
    ...
    <Navbar className="Header red" brand={Img} right />
}
```

The syntax for inserting an image is slightly different so I thought I'd include this in here along with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/react-materialize/react-materialize/issues/326) you may need to wrap what you want to change in a `div` and change the class on that. Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately no. That does work in the case of NavItems, as I have done above. However for in the case of `brand` There is no way to wrap it with a `div` tag.

Comment: When you mention `brand` what specifically are you referring to? The `Navbar` has a `brand` attribute, but your CSS also refers to the `brand-logo` class. Speaking of which, where does the latter appear in your HTML? It does not appear in the snippet you provided.

Comment: I'm referring specifically to the `brand` attribute of `Navbar` as you have stated. The latter, `.brand-logo`, does not appear in the HTML, it is a `Materialize` class which I had to use to manually change the color since the normal methods were not working.

Comment: In that case, I'm a bit confused. How did `nav .brand-logo` as a CSS selector work since no elements in the code you provided have the `.brand-logo` class? Is there other HTML on the page you did not include in the snippet?

Comment: No, all the code is there. `nav .brand-logo` works as a selector since `Navbar` in `react-materialize` compiles a `nav` element in the generated HTML. I used the inspector to find the element on the page, which ended up being a `nav` element with a class of `brand-logo`. I hope that is more clear.

Comment: Ah, I see. I haven't specifically used `react-materialize` myself so I think I was overlooking the fact that some of the HTML classes were being added dynamically when the page rendered.